# Is the protective armour in the shooting scene in Wrath of Man realistic?

Tags: realism, wrath-of-man

There is quite a long shooting scene in the movie, where antagonists wear some sort of protective armour that is capable of protecting them from numerous bullet hits from the relatively close range. While the men in the armour are repeatedly hit numerous times from automatic weapons, their armour is apparently able to keep them safe, unless a bullet hits some spot between the protective sheets.

[image: screencap of said scene]

Are there any real-world types of armour that have similar protective capabilities, while being of relatively the same thickness as in the movie?

Comment: Likely not, since it sounds like they don’t take transfer of momentum into account. (Kevlar can keep a bullet from breaking your skin but the energy of the bullet is still transferred to the Kevlar and thence to your body for heavy bruising).

Comment: As - based on a quick search - it seems this film revolves around security, armour, protective gear, and so on, this question sounds like it's not mere trivia.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of force that an impact from a bullet can make, especially from close range, is immense. Even with Kevlar on, the impact could break a bone, depending on the range and caliber of weapon. For someone to not flinch on impact is purely for cinematic entertainment.

Answer (score 0):

There's a kind of armour called 'Dragon armour' that can definitely withstand multiple shots from lower-energy non-armour-piercing rounds such as 9mm or 45 ACP, just not to the same exact spot.

That said what @Benedict says is true that the target wouldn't be able to just stand there unaffected.

Answer (score -2):

Haven't seen the show, but there are body armours that can stand up to multiple hits even from rifle calibres.

This Wikipedia page shows what various levels of body armour is rated to stop: [List of body armor performance standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_body_armor_performance_standards).